# Error when using GetAll (AsyncCrudAppService) and apply sorting

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've built an application service based on the AsyncCrudAppService class, like this:

```
public class ServiceTemplateAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<ServiceTemplate, ServiceTemplateDto, int, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, CreateServiceTemplateDto, UpdateServiceTemplateDto>, IServiceTemplateAppService
```

Everything works as intended, but once in a while I get an error when calling the GetAll method and passing in a sorting parameter, like this:

```
api/services/app/CostCenter/GetAll?SkipCount=0&MaxResultCount=10&Sorting=displayName%20asc
```

I have overridden the CreateFilteredQuery method and it now looks like this because I want to get some child entities.

```
protected override IQueryable<ServiceTemplate> CreateFilteredQuery(PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
{
     return Repository.GetAll()
         .Include(x => x.ServiceTemplateRole)
             .ThenInclude(y => y.Role)
         .Include(x => x.ServiceTemplateImage)
         .Include(x => x.ServiceTemplateCategory);
 }
```

The error message that I get is this one:

```
INFO  2018-11-16 13:45:02,101 [21   ] ore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker - Route matched with {area = "app", action = "GetAll", controller = "ServiceTemplate"}. Executing action dsim.Services.ServiceTemplateAppService.GetAll (dsim.Application)
INFO  2018-11-16 13:45:02,104 [21   ] ore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker - Executing action method dsim.Services.ServiceTemplateAppService.GetAll (dsim.Application) with arguments (Abp.Application.Services.Dto.PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto) - Validation state: Valid
ERROR 2018-11-16 13:45:02,189 [24   ] Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.BindableTypeAttribute' from assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.BindableTypeAttribute' from assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.CustomTypeProviders.AbstractDynamicLinqCustomTypeProvider.<>c.<FindTypesMarkedWithDynamicLinqTypeAttribute>b__0_1(Type x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.CustomTypeProviders.DefaultDynamicLinqCustomTypeProvider.GetCustomTypes()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.KeywordsHelper..ctor(ParsingConfig config)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser..ctor(ParameterExpression[] parameters, String expression, Object[] values, ParsingConfig parsingConfig)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.OrderBy(IQueryable source, ParsingConfig config, String ordering, Object[] args)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.OrderBy[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, ParsingConfig config, String ordering, Object[] args)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.OrderBy[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, String ordering, Object[] args)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.CrudAppServiceBase`6_ApplySorting_3.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.PerformSyncUow(IInvocation invocation, UnitOfWorkOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.ServiceTemplateAppServiceProxy.ApplySorting(IQueryable`1 query, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
   at Abp.Application.Services.AsyncCrudAppService`8.GetAll(TGetAllInput input)
   at Abp.Threading.InternalAsyncHelper.AwaitTaskWithPostActionAndFinallyAndGetResult[T](Task`1 actualReturnValue, Func`1 postAction, Action`1 finalAction)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()
```

I've tried to figure out what could cause the problem and adding the assembly that the exceptions tells me, but no progress. The strange thing is that this sometimes work, so my guess is that is has something to do with the actual data in the DB, but hey?! I don't know...

Comment: but the exception message is literally telling you what the problem is - have you tried addressing it?

Answer (score 1):

`GetAll` Method From AsyncCrudAppService calls `ApplySorting` Method, you can override it and there sort as you want.

```
    protected override IQueryable<YourEntity> ApplySorting(IQueryable<YourEntity> query, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
    {
        if (input.Sorting.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            input.Sorting = "yourColumn asc";
        }
        return base.ApplySorting(query, input);
    }
```

If you want to crate another `GetAll` Method here is an example:

```
public Task<PagedResultDto<PaisDto>> GetAllFiltered(PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input, string filter)
        {
            var paisList = new List<Pais>();
            var query = Repository.GetAll();

            query = ApplySorting(query, input);


            if (filter != null && filter != string.Empty)
            {
                paisList = query
                    .Where(x => x.Identificador.StartsWith(filter) || x.Nombre.StartsWith(filter))
                    .Skip(input.SkipCount)
                    .Take(input.MaxResultCount).ToList();

                var result = new PagedResultDto<PaisDto>(query.Count(), ObjectMapper.Map<List<PaisDto>>(paisList));
                return Task.FromResult(result);
            }
            else
            {

                paisList = query
                    .Skip(input.SkipCount)
                    .Take(input.MaxResultCount).ToList()
                    .ToList();

                var result = new PagedResultDto<PaisDto>(query.Count(), ObjectMapper.Map<List<PaisDto>>(paisList));
                return Task.FromResult(result);
            }
        }
```

**query = ApplySorting(query, input);** in this line you can call base method `base.ApplySorting(query, input);`